# Rails find entries with specific atribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im rails beginner and tried to list only database entries with an specific attribute.
In this case number:string = '40829'.
But it didnt worked out for me, here is my controller:

```
def index
    @ebms = Ebm.find(params[:number => '40829'])
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `where`, like so

```
Ebm.where(number: '40829')
```

or

```
Ebm.find_by_number('40829')
```

Please read the documentation about [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an additional answer.. If you need this very often throughout your application, you can create a scope. This has the advantage, that if you have to change your special number once to an other number, you only need to change one piece of code, and not all over your application. (Rails4 syntax)

```
# your model app/models/ebm.rb
class Ebm < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :my_scope_name, -> { where(:number => "40829") }
end

# usage in controller
def index
  @ebms = Ebm.my_scope_name
end
```

More information about scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Answer (score 0):

you should try this :

```
def index
  @ebms = Ebm.where(number: '40829')
end

or 

def index
  @ebms = Ebm.find_by_number('40829')
end
```

Comment: because I took much time to answer is properly. Thats why..:(